# Prompting user before paging Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way I can create something like a "are you sure?" when the user tries to page a kendo grid.

However, there is no event like "beforePaging" or something.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495593/how-to-prompt-user-that-edits-have-been-made-upon-changing-pages-or-sorting-in-k) with the exact same issue but the answer there doesn't do anything for me (using requestStart).

I tried to add an event listener for the paging buttons and it went ok, but I can't cancel the paging event as it is not directly bound to the paging:

```
$(document).on("click", ".k-pager-numbers li a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Handler for .click() called");
});
```

The above is called, but the `preventDefault` doesn't prevent paging, as `e` is not the actual paging event.

Comment: used `Confirm` instead of `alert`

Comment: if you want confirmation before preceding in such case use `Confirm` in `if` block

Comment: @JaydipJ,wWell, that is the same thing, the paging is never prevented, whether I use confirm or anything else. The issue here is, I can catch the click event on the paging link, but the paging event itself I can't catch and therefore, can't prevent it based on any condition I wanted

Answer (score 0):

There is now good or proper way for this, but you can use code below. Put in on DataSource [requestStart](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestStart) event.

```
requestStart: function(e) {
  if (e.type == "read" && this.hasChanges()) {
      if (confirm("You need to fill information before...") == false) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
      }
  }
},
```

Comment: Where does this go? To the datasource definition? Can you post more code around that?

Comment: Updated my answer. See link for requestStart.

Comment: Thanks Jarno, I will try this later today